# check which event handler handles alt+a combination on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to determine event handler from all javascript code connected with the site that handles a specific key combination?

In my input, I'm unable to type in a letter like ą which is Polish. It can be done typing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>.

I'm using [jQuery UI 1.9](http://jqueryui.com/).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you simply trying to restrict input? What specific key code produces the ą character? alt + a did not work for me.

Comment: You need to have a certain keyboard layout set in your system for this to work. I believe the OP isn't trying to restrict input, he is suffering from this happening in some webapp he uses...

Comment: Sadly, this is still a non-trivial topic. If you solved the problem, it would be nice if you shared which approach worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) to check all the event listeners on your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can run through all of the events that were bound with jQuery:

```
$._data( element, "events" );
```

This returns an object that shows all events that have been bound. You can then cycle through and check which has the handler you're looking for. Passing this to your console should allow you to quickly break down the members and examine the object as a whole with ease.

Unfortunately, this won't show you events that were bound natively using `attachEvent` or `addEventListener`. Those you would have to check the properties on the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use Chrome Developer Tools' *Event Listener Breakpoints* functionality, open up CDT and go to `Sources -> Event Listener Breakpoints (in the right sidebar) -> Keyboard`, then tick the `keyup` event.

The debugger will take you to the handler next time you press a key. That would still require some digging around (and basic undersanding of jquery  code) but still helpful. 
The upside is that you don't need to know which elements in the DOM hierarchy have the key event bound, CDT will catch 'em all.

Also, try searching the source (of the app, not the jquery library itself) for [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).